# не устанавливается русский в pyttsx3

Tags: pyttsx3

Не получается изменить голос, при запуске текст воспроизводиться максиммально плохим голосом, и выдаёт `Full dictionary is not installed for 'ru'`
код ниже:

````
    import pyttsx3
    tts = pyttsx3.init()
    tts.setProperty('voice', 'russian')
    tts.say('какой-нибудь текст')
    tts.runAndWait()```
````

Answer (score 0):

Установи с гит хаба: pip install git+https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3